# Angular 2 with JQuery DataTable Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular, datatables-1.10

I want to call an API from my Angular 2 application with Jquery DataTable Ajax call.

Request was successful but the parameters for the request been converted to Query String Parameters when i looked into Google Chrome Network tab it is like

```
=%7B&1=%22&2=T&3=a&4=b&5=l&6=e&7=S&8=c&9=h&10=e&11=m&12=a&13=%22&14=%3A&15=%22&16=T&17=1&18=%22&19=%7D&_=1487761201305
```

And when i call API from Angular 2 Http.post and looked into Google Chrome Network tab the request contains Request Payload its like

```
{TableSchema: "T1", RoleID: 1}
```

I want to send data like Angular 2 Http.post. How can i do from Jquery DataTable Ajax ?