# I dont want my parameters to be encoded while Ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't want my parameters to be encoded while ajax post.

Debugged via Chrome:

```
=%7B&1=%22&2=T&3=a&4=b&5=l&6=e&7=S&8=c&9=h&10=e&11=m&12=a&13=%22&14=%3A&15=%22&16=T&17=1&18=%22&19=%7D&_=1487761201305
```

Comment: Why would you not want this? It's part of the standards for encoding values placed in URLs to ensure they don't interfere with the formatting of the URL itself

Comment: Please rephrase this as a question with your "desired" functionality - like how would you avoid the encode to convey the same information? (and need to decode yourself) with some details on your new "standard" - or clarify your desire/intent as it is not to obvious

Comment: Actually @RoryMcCrossan, what i need was, in my angular 2 http post data where sent as like this in request payload {TableSchema: "T1", RoleID: 1} (objects) but when i try through ajax post  it been sent like this TableSchema=T1

Comment: Can you look into it, my actual query is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389598/angular-2-with-jquery-datatable-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

### Use method post in jQuery Ajax

```
var data = {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  };

$.ajax({
  url: 'url.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {data:data},
  success: function(res) {
   console.log(res)
  }
});
```